Canister is out of Cycles but I still have cycles
I am new to motoko and am trying to deploy an app onto the ICP Network. When i try to run
dfx deploy --network

there is an error saying that the canister is out of cycles.
When I check the balance of the wallet using
dfx wallet --network=ic balance

it returns 2.097 trillion cycles.
Why are the cycles not in the canister?
